# How to dump only a certain part of SVN repository?

Tags: svn

How to you move a *part* of an SVN repository into a new repository?

To move the contents of a complete SVN repository into a new repository, one has to dump the old repository first:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repository-name.dmp
```

and then load it into the new one using `svnadmin load`.

But I'm not sure how to just move a part. Do I still have to dump the whole thing? Do I grep for the part that I want?

To just dump `myproject`, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository/myproject
```

Comment: Or does this belong on serverfault.com?

Comment: .. I think you'd probably find the answer on serverfault, but I think these days there are enough "power users" using SVN on their local machines for it to be worth leaving here.  It got votes!

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `svndumpfilter` for stuff like this.  In particular `svndumpfilter include`.  So for your case:

```
svndumpfilter include myproject < repository-name.dmp > myproject.dmp
svnadmin load /path/to/myproject-repo < myproject.dmp
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.commands.c.include.html

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering

Answer (score 7):

If your repository is hosted at an URL you can use `svnrdump` to dump a sub-folder of the repository:

```
svnrdump dump http://svn.example.com/repos/[.../]project
```

where *repos* is the root of the repository and *project* is the sub-folder that you want to dump.